# Dynamic readjustment of image size in ImageView in android

Tags: android

I need to know how to go about resizing an image automatically on different screen sizes.

I have an ImageView on my activity, and I've specified its `layout_height` and `layout_width` as 50dp each. Now I want the size of the image to upscale or downscale with respect to the screen dimensions/resolution of various devices, but it's displaying the image with the same size, thus looking too small in the tablet and just right in a cellphone.
Moreover, if I use `wrap_content` instead for the width and height, it looks too big on the cellphone and just right on the tablet.

So how do I go about fixing it?

P.s. I've been using Android Emulator Nexus 4 (for the cellphone; 768x1280 xhdpi) and Nexus 9 (for the tablet; 2048x1563 xhdpi).

Comment: Have you tried using ImageView's ScaleTypes?  Or is there a reason you can't use these?  Or using an @dimen for different screen sizes?

Comment: @Submersed, I did try to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` here, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide images for different screen densities in order to support all the devices. Generate them using the [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) or [Image baker](https://www.img-bak.in/) or any other design tool.

You then need to move them to your resource directory.

```
res/drawable-mdpi/myimage.png
res/drawable-hdpi/myimage.png
res/drawable-xhdpi/myimage.png
res/drawable-xxhdpi/myimage.png
```

Read more about [Supporting different screens](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) and [Designing for Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).

Comment: I already am following this approach, but as mentioned in the question, `wrap_content` gives me too big of images on the cell but just right for the tab, while restricting it to 50dp yields an opposite result. P.s. sizes are as follows: mdpi (130x130), hdpi (195x195), xhdpi (260x260), xxhdpi (390x390) and xxxhdpi (520x520)

Comment: Also, since I'm testing this on Android Emulators, both of them (Nexus 4 and Nexus 9) are of the same dpi, i.e. xhdpi as mentioned in the question, so your proposed solution might not work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something similar to this recently, and it might not be the best solution since it uses the layout pass to animate, but it worked for my use case.  I needed to scale the the image to fit within a container, while maintaining the original aspect ratio.  There is a ScaleType for this, but I also needed to keep track of how much the image was scaled so I could translate other points to appear correctly on the scaled up image, relative to the original.  Depending on your use case, this could be a little overkill, but here's how I approached it:

Define your XML with at least 2 views, one will act as your  maximum bounds that your ImageView can fill, and the other will be your ImageView to scale -- I was lazy and did this with an invisible View (note that I removed some views, since they were specific to my project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <!-- This is the ImageView we're setting the bitmap on, that we'll be scaling -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <!-- Being lazy here and using an invisible view for measuring our max bounds, use RelativeLayouts layout params to bound this appropriately to your use case i.e. layout_above, layout_below, etc -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/image_max_scale"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After defining a View define 3 rects (I needed these to be global, you may not -- also, I'll be providing examples in Kotlin):

```
private val originalBounds = RectF()
private val maxContainerBounds = RectF()
private val finalBounds = RectF()
```

After your View is created, load in your Bitmap and set it on your ImageView.  Before you set it on the ImageView, add a OnPreDrawListener to your View's ViewTreeObserver.  This will allow you to grab the measured bounds of your maximum bounding box, as well as the size of your ImageView when it's initially set (since we're initially using wrap_content):

```
            image.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                    image.getLocalVisibleRect(originalBounds)
                    image_max_scale.getLocalVisibleRect(maxContainerBounds)

                    image.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                    image.post {
                        animateImageContainerScale()
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })

            image.setImageBitmap(it)
```

So, now we have 2 Rects for our bounds, we can animate our ImageView to fit within those bounds:

```
//Provides getWidth(), setWidth(), getHeight(), setHeight() for property animation
    class BoundListener(w: Int, h: Int) {
        var width: Int = w
        var height: Int = h
    }

private fun animateImageContainerScale() {
    finalBounds.set(originalBounds)

    val scaleMatrix = Matrix()
    scaleMatrix.setRectToRect(originalBounds, maxContainerBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER)
    scaleMatrix.mapRect(finalBounds, originalBounds)

    val valueReceiver = BoundListener(originalBounds.width().toInt(), originalBounds.height().toInt())
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(valueReceiver,
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("width", finalBounds.width().toInt()),
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("height", finalBounds.height().toInt()))
    animator.addUpdateListener {
        image.layoutParams.width = valueReceiver.width
        image.layoutParams.height = valueReceiver.height
        image.requestLayout()
    }
    animator.setAutoCancel(true)
    animator.start()
}
```

This should animate the ImageView to fit within the maximum bounds, or if you want to skip animation just set the width and height to the appropriate finalBounds values.